# Data frame column: Convert only numbers to int, words to remain as strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As shown in the screenshot below, I have 2 columns in an excel file. I'm trying to reduce the precision of the number fields eg 100.54000000000001 to 100.540. The number is stored as string, so when I convert it to float using

```
df['Unnamed: 5'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Unnamed: 5'], errors='coerce')
```

it converts strings to NaN. Can anyone help me with issue? I'm trying to convert only numbers to int, and words should remain strings.

[image: screenshot of the data]

EDIT: It would be acceptable to convert the numeric values back to string after rounding them.  My code is as follows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> xl = pd.ExcelFile("WSJ_template.xls") 
>>> xl.sheet_names 
[u'losers', u'winners'] 
>>> dfw = xl.parse("winners") 
>>> dfw.head() 
<output>
>>> dfw = dfw.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').combine_first(dfw) 
>>> dfw = dfw.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) 
>>> dfw
<output>
```

Comment: You can't mix data types within a column of a dataframe.  would you be happy with the data being converted back to str after being rounded?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would work too.
I created a code, and sent it to the guy to incorporate into his SQL code, but it didn't work for him. I use jupyter, and he uses something else. My code is as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xl = pd.ExcelFile("WSJ_template.xls")
xl.sheet_names
[u'losers', u'winners']
dfw = xl.parse("winners")
dfw.head()
dfw = dfw.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').combine_first(dfw)
dfw = dfw.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
dfw

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already identified, we're best off using [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).  The only difference is rather than using a built-in function, we'll define our own.

We'll start off by filling the DataFrame (this is a placeholder, you already have this covered):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6'],
                  data=[['NaN', 'NaN'], 
                        ['Average', 'Weekly'], 
                        ['100.540000000001', '0.2399999999999999'],
                        ['99.3299999999998', '0.1700000000000001'],
                        ['95.4800000000004', 'change'],
                        ['bid', '1.929999999999999']])
```

Now we define a function to use to convert values.  This function should try to cast to float and if it works, return the rounded value.  If it doesn't work, just return the original value.  Here's one possible route:

```
def round_only_nums(val):
    try:
        return '%s' % round(float(val), 3)
    except:
        return val
```

Next, let's apply that the columns that need processing:

```
cols_to_process = ['Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']
for col in cols_to_process:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(round_only_nums)
```

And our results:

```
>>> df
  Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
0        nan        nan
1    Average     Weekly
2     100.54       0.24
3      99.33       0.17
4      95.48     change
5        bid       1.93
```